# How should I use exact keyword matching as a condition in the case statement?

Tags: regex, bash

I was trying to write myself some handy scripts in order to <strike>legitimately slacking off</strike> work more efficiently, and this question suddenly popped up:

Given a very long string `$LONGEST_EVER_STRING` and several keywords strings like `$A='foo bar'` , `$B='omg bbq'` and `$C='stack overflow'`

How should I use exact keyword matching as a condition in the `case` statement?

```
for word in $LONGEST_EVER_STRING; do
  case $word in
    any exact match in $A) do something ;;
    any exact match in $B) do something ;;
    any exact match in $C) do something ;;
    *)  do something else;;
  esac
done
```

I know I can write in this way but it looks really ugly:

```
for word in $LONGEST_EVER_STRING; do
  if [[ -n $(echo $A | fgrep -w $word) ]]; then
    do something;
  elif [[ -n $(echo $B | fgrep -w $word) ]]; then
    do something;
  elif [[ -n $(echo $C | fgrep -w $word) ]]; then
    do something;
  else
    do something else;
  fi
done
```

Does anyone have an elegant solution? Many thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example input and output, please?

Comment: My string "${LONGEST_EVER_STRING}foo" is even longer...

Comment: So IMHO we should take this opportunity to announce the beginning of the SOers-GOT-LONG-STRING contest 2014 @twalberg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a function to do a little transform in your A, B, C variables and then:

```
shopt -s extglob
Ax="+(foo|bar)"
Bx="+(omg|bbq)"
Cx="+(stack|overflow)"
for word in $LONGEST_EVER_STRING; do
  case $word in
    $Ax) do something ;;
    $Bx) do something ;;
    $Cx) do something ;;
    *)  do something else;;
  esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just define a function for this. It'll be slower than grep for large wordlists, but faster than starting up grep many times.

```
##
# Success if the first arg is one of the later args.
has() {
  [[ $1 = $2 ]] || {
    [[ $3 ]] && has "$1" "${@:3}"
  }
}

$ has a b c && echo t || echo f
f
$ has a b c a d e f && echo t || echo f
t
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation on /etc/bashrc's "pathmunge"

```
for word in $LONGEST_EVER_STRING; do
    found_word=false
    for list in " $A " " $B " " $C "; do
        if [[ $list == *" $word "* ]]; then 
            found_word=true
            stuff with $list and $word
            break
        fi
    done
    $found_word || stuff when not found
done
```